# Saying "very much" right after "Nice to meet you, too"

Tags: phrase-request, greetings

Can I say "very much" right after  "Nice to meet you, too."? The other day I was introduced to one native English speaker and said that - just to emphasize how glad I was, but he looked a bit puzzled by what I said.

It was me who said, "Nice to meet you, too", which was in response to his "Nice to meet you."

If what I did was wrong, then what was the right way in English to emphasize the fact that I am glad to meet a person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nice to meet you, too!" is a perfectly fine response to "Nice to meet you."

However, you can't just add "very much" anywhere. "Nice to meet you, very much" would be grammatically incorrect. If you wanted to express intensity, you should say "Very nice to meet you!" (If you add "too" at the end, that would mean that your response matches the intensity of his initial greeting. That's mildly awkward, if you added "very". and he didn't say "very".)

In very extreme circumstances, you might say: "I'm so glad to have a chance to meet you at last! I've been a great fan of your artwork!"

Comment: We can add _very much_ to an expression like, "Thank you," (as in, "Thank you very much"), but, for some reason, it doesn't work with "Nice to meet you." We could, however, put a _very_ in the front: "Very glad to meet you, too."

Answer (score 1):

"It's nice to meet you too, very much," is grammatically fine; but I think a more natural way of saying it would be: "It's very nice to meet you too."

However, I think the reason for his surprise was more because you veered from the standard script in that situation. "Nice to meet you" is the kind of thing a person says automatically, without real meaning behind it; and the standard response is either "Nice to meet you too" or just "You too." He probably just wasn't expecting you to add more to it.

Answer (score 1):

That's very much acceptable response what you gave. Here one expression which I heard from my trainer, when I said, "Nice to meet you," in reply he expressed: "Same here" ...just two words.

Hope this is okay with native English speakers..

Comment: It's not really an acceptable response.

Comment: @superato - I disagree. That brief response may be a little too curt for, say, a formal business meeting, but it works just fine at a place like the gym. The expression "same here" even gets its own entry in some dictionaries, such as [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/same-here), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/same%20here), and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/same_here).